# Variable assignment based on condition

Tags: if-statement, rust

I try to assign a PathBuf result to variable based on a condition:

```
// USE_OLD_DATA set at compilation time to FALSE or TRUE
let root = env::current_dir().unwrap();

let processed_files_location = if USE_OLD_DATA {
    root.join("Result Data 10-28-2020");
} else {
    root.join("Result Data");
};
```

after this ... the processed_files_location = () ?!

Comment: just remove the `;` at the end of each `if`/`else` block. With the `;`, the *value* of the alternative is nothing, i.e. `()` in Rust.

Comment: Also note that when compiling this code, it gives this warning: `warning: unused return value of 'Path::join' that must be used`. That is a hint that the result is being thrown away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since conditionals are expressions,  you can just pass the expression to your `join` method:

```rs
let processed_files_location =
    root.join(
        if USE_OLD_DATA {
            "Result Data 10-28-2020"
        } else {
            "Result Data"
        }
    );
```

And, as pointed out in the comments, when you terminate your branch expressions with `;`, it evaluates to the unit tuple `()` rather than the type you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks .. this makes the IF/ELSE branches less costly too :)